# Adding class to some field items in twig template

Tags: php, arrays, twig

Imagine I have two arrays. One contains all items, the other contains only selected items. I have rendered all items in a twig template:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to add class (like `selected-item`) to those items that is selected.
 I tried this, class added correctly but the loop wasn't

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% for selectedItem in selectedItems %}
     {% if selectedItem == item %}
        <li class="item-selected">{{ selectedItem }}</li>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Result:

```
Administration         // selected-item
Administration
Advertising
Finance
Marketing
Sales
Staff
Staff                  // selected-item
```

What I want:

```
Administration         // selected-item
Advertising
Finance
Marketing
Sales
Staff                  // selected-item
```

Please tell me how it should be?

Comment: You could just use the test `in` `{% for item in items %}{% if item in selectedItems %}...{% endif %}...{% endfor %}`

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Obviously, you render a `<li>` both within that inner condition and in the loop itself

Comment: @NicoHaase yeah, i know my loop was wrong cause it looped 2 times. One in the condition and one in the normal loop. Didn't know I can use ```in``` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DarkBee! I just have to change the loop condition to this and it worked

```
{% for item in termNames %}
   {% if item in selectedTerms %}
      <li class="selected-term">{{ item }}</li>
   {% else %}
      <li>{{ item }}</li>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```